# Can't relock bootloader

Tags: recovery-mode, bootloader

So i'm trying to relock my bootloader after unlocking it. I have a Realme 5 pro and i tried relocking it using adb and `fastboot flashing lock` but it gives me the following error:
`FAILED (command write failed (No error)).`

I've heard that amd cpus give some trouble regarding adb commands and rooting and stuff so also tried on an intel machine but the issue is still the same. Can anyone help me out. Also sorry to mix another question in but i also wanted to know if factory resetting the phone relocks the bootloader since i can't find a clear answer related to it.
[image]

Comment: you know in order to **lock** bootloader device must completely stock ROM/firmware don't you? furthermore you will lose ability for fastboot flash

Comment: @alecxs i didn't know that. i'm fairly new to the rooting scene. thanks for the info